# web3 transaction details

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Are there any functionalities available on web3.js to provide the details Etheresacn provides, such as Txn Type, the Base fee per gas, etc.

I am aware of `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt` however, it is missing the above attributes.

Here is an example to transaction details on Etherscan (https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfadaad55279b536b18225aec6f485034ab157fefed65b98da14f22954b00c303)

Answer (score 0):

I just connected to Infura node using web3.py and here is output of the following command:

```
w3.eth.get_transaction(0x847dc489014532d6c8805a9c90260ce67994adedca3598e6ba9e6839d4d472be)

AttributeDict(
{'accessList': [], 
'blockHash': HexBytes('0x26ddf1189d0f8473b6640e1113beed5934e5e621ea994e5bf37d4255dee8a9da'), 
'blockNumber': 13124873, 
'chainId': '0x1', 
'from': '0x5A0b54D5dc17e0AadC383d2db43B0a0D3E029c4c', 
'gas': 100000, 
'gasPrice': 98943318241, 
'hash': HexBytes('0x847dc489014532d6c8805a9c90260ce67994adedca3598e6ba9e6839d4d472be'), 
'input': '0x', 'maxFeePerGas': '0x559b9368f4', 'maxPriorityFeePerGas': '0x0', 
'nonce': 6061436, 
'r': HexBytes('0xa374a0cb796071ba58db3bbb7f923cd5ae4eda77068269f67fa6c9b1de28e6f3'), 
's': HexBytes('0xf834d3e491609efcb4a43169adc765335370de4d273ce55a7d113dc686e955'), 
'to': '0x8fD00f170FDf3772C5ebdCD90bF257316c69BA45', 
'transactionIndex': 43, 
'type': '0x2', 
'v': 0, 
'value': 98012341188637423626})
```

Some details can be computered using the above command.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to get those information directly. But you can use bytecode as a hint. [Here](https://medium.com/@codetractio/inside-an-ethereum-transaction-fa94ffca912f) is a link for you to understanding deeply.

Comment: Wonder how etherscan retrieves those details